# How to extend MIPS bus error handlers?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux, archlinux

I'm writing a Linux driver in MIPS architecture.
there I implement read operation - read some registers content.
Here is the code:

```
static int proc_seq_show(struct seq_file *seq, void *v)  
{  
  volatile unsigned reg;
  //here read registers and pass to user using seq_printf  
  //1. read reg number 1
  //2. read reg number 2 
}
int proc_open(struct inode *inode, struct file *filp)
{  
  return single_open(filp,&proc_seq_show, NULL);
}

static struct file_operation proc_ops = {.read = &seq_read, .open=&seq_open};
```

My problem is that reading register content sometimes causing kernel oops - bus error, and read operation is prevented. I can't avoid it in advance.

Since this behavior is acceptable I would like to ignore this error and continue to read the other registers.

I saw bus error handler in the kernel (do_be in traps.c), there is an option to add my own entry to the __dbe_table. An entry looks like that:

```
struct exception_table_entry {unsigned long insn, nextinsn; };
```

***insn*** is the instruction that cause the error. ***nextinsn*** is the next instruction to be performed after exception.
In the driver I declare an entry:

```
struct exception_table_entry e __attribute__ ((section("__dbe_table"))) = {0,0};
```

but I don't know how to initialize it. How can I get the instruction address of the risky line in C? how can I get the address of the fix line? I have tried something with labels and addresses of label -  but didn't manage to set correctly the exception_table_entry .

The same infrastructure is available in x86, does someone know how they use it?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Something sounds fishy to me, but I am no MIPS expert. Instead of working around a symptom you should probably determine the root cause of the bad address and fix it.

Comment: I can't root cause it and fix. That's why MIPS added this infrastructure to their code - to allow developers to provide their own fixup.